# Sorting is showing lower scored answer above higher one, neither accepted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, voting, sorting

It was my understanding that answers to questions on all SE sites are sorted by descending net votes, with the accepted answer (if there is one) pinned to the top.

However, the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/374976/what-is-the-point-to-120hz-in-2d-mode) are sorting for me as:

- +15 (accepted answer)
- **-1**
- +6
- +6
- +1

How can this happen?

Comment: Are you on active?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you are viewing answers sorted based on last active date.

This will override the default answer scores sorting and show the answer with the last activity (posting or editing) topmost.